# How can I use a logarithmic ScalingFunctions with ListContourPlot and DataRange? (i.e. no x- and y- inputs given)

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale, scaling

There appears to be a bug in plotting, using `ListContourPlot` with `ScalingFunctions->{"Log","Log"}` and specifying a `DataRange`, when trying to plot only a 2d array (i.e. with the x- and y- variables specified using `DataRange` instead of being input).
Providing a 2d `DataRange` gives a blank plot, with `PlotRange` having no effect.  If I include "All" as a 3rd dimension to `DataRange`, then the plot draws axes as `Exp[DataRange]`.

Could somebody help me around this apparent bug?

Comment: Add code example.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `ScalingFunctions` does not work with numbers below the base of the logarithm. Conider e.g.:
n = 20;

```
dat = Table[x^2 + y^2, {x, 1, n}, {y, 1, 2 n}];
ListContourPlot[dat, DataRange -> {{1, n}, {1, 2 n}}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log2"}]
```

[image]

Or the same with `Log10`:

```
n = 20;
dat = Table[x^2 + y^2, {x, 1, n}, {y, 1, 2 n}];
ListContourPlot[dat, DataRange -> {{1, n}, {1, 2 n}}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log10"}]
```

[image]

I think this is a bug. Please report it to "support.wolfram.com"

Comment: What if PlotRange matches DataRange? For example, `ListContourPlot[dat, DataRange -> {{1, n}, {1, 2n}}, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log10"}, PlotRange -> {{E^1, E^n }, {10^1, 10^(2n)}}]`. Without the explicit PlotRange, MMA uses “pleasing” axes scales. I don’t think this is a bug.

Comment: Explicitly setting DataRange limits which match the PlotRange does not help; I think there is a bug here.